# Run the tasks in a node twice

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am using the Jenkins pipeline plugin to test my project. I have a Groovy script of the following form:

```
node {

   stage("checkout") {
     //some other code
   }

   stage("build") {
     //some other code
   }

   stage("SonarQube Analysis") {
     //some other code
   }

}
```

When I have a feature branch that I want to merge into `master`, I would like to first do this process on `master`, then on the feature and see if the SonarQube analysis is worse on feature.

I would like something of this sort:

```
def codeCoverageMaster = node("master")
def codeCoverageFeature = node("feature/someFeature")
if(codeCoverageFeature < codeCoverageMaster) {
   currentBuild.result = "ERROR"
}
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You do it by defining a function which contain your script and return the SonarQube result, then you call the function twice and compare the result:

```
def runBranch(String path) {
  def sonarQubeRes
  node {

    stage("checkout") {
      //some other code
      // Use path supplied to this function
    }

    stage("build") {
      //some other code
    }

    stage("SonarQube Analysis") {
      //some other code
    }

  }
  return sonarQubeRes
}

def codeCoverageMaster = runBranch("master")
def codeCoverageFeature = runBranch("feature/someFeature")
if(codeCoverageFeature < codeCoverageMaster) {
  currentBuild.result = "ERROR"
}
```